# Show line at opening brace when cursor is after the closing brace (Perl)

Tags: minibuffer, perl, pairing

Something I like in Emacs is positioning the cursor after the closing brace/paren highlights the opening brace/paren.

Even better, like in `Emacs-Lisp` mode, the opening `(` line is displayed in the minibuffer. This is convenient when that line is too high up and cannot be seen in the display.

In `Perl` and `CPerl` mode, however, the opening `{` line is not shown in the minibuffer. Is there a way to have it shown?

*Edit* Tried to rename my .emacs / .emacs.d (in case the long config wrote a long time ago would interfere), but that didn't improve anything in these Perl modes.

(*using Emacs 26.3 GUI on Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04*)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with `emacs -Q` on version 26.3 and it works for me: it moves the cursor for a second to the matching opening brace if that is visible and it prints the matching line in the echo area if it is not.

Check the value of `post-self-insert-hook` with `C-h v post-self-insert-hook RET` - my setting is:

```el
(electric-indent-post-self-insert-function blink-paren-post-self-insert-function)
```

If yours is missing the `blink-paren-...` function, you can add it with

```el
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'blink-paren-post-self-insert-function)
```

somewhere in your init file. But you should investigate *why* you are not getting that: AFAICT, it should be the out-of-the-box default.

The OP indicates that this is already the case in their setup, so we'll have to dig one level deeper. The variable `blink-paren-function` is used by `blink-paren-post-self-insert-function` - doing `C-h v blink-paren-function RET` shows:

> Its value is ‘blink-matching-open’

in my case. Now if I place my cursor after the closing brace and do `M-x blink-matching-open RET` I see the matching line in the echo area.

So check that the variable is set to the function - if not, set it:

```el
(setq blink-paren-function #'blink-matching-open)
```

and also execute `blink-matching-open` with the invocation above and check that it produces the appropriate indications

BTW, all of the above was done in a GUI instance of emacs: I did not test in terminal emacs.

Comment: Interesting, but my `post-self-insert-hook` var has already that hook value. I renamed my old and well-filled `.emacs` & `.emacs.d` before starting Emacs, but that didn't improve anything (and that var is also set in that case). It probably has to do with the *Perl* and *CPerl* modes.

Comment: Edited with a couple of additional things to check. BTW, as long as the hook is set, I don't think Perl/CPerl mode has anything to do with it: I changed the mode to `text-mode` and I still get the matching blink/message. Ditto for `fundamental-mode`.